# How do I work with NEST when a type have BSonDocument as properties

Tags: nest

We currently have an object that has BSon value types as properties.
When trying to use NEST (instead of elasticsearch.net) we get a serialization exception on AsBoolan property, which is part of the BsonValue type.

How should I use NEST when a type has BSon types.
Specifically we use a BSonDocument to have dynamic properties.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the requirement to use BSON types? Json.net and in effect NEST works well with dynamic or Dictionary<string, object> if you need dynamic properties. I have never used/tested BsonDocuments.